# Django ImportError: cannot import name VERSION_CHANGE

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I need a help to understand about this error, Im getting this error while creating the Django-CMS project, Can anyone tell me why im getting this error and how to overcome this, Thank you.

```
from reversion.models import VERSION_CHANGE
ImportError: cannot import name VERSION_CHANGE
Creating the projectFailure occurred.
```

Output for `pip freeze` :

```
 Django==1.6.10
Pillow==2.7.0
South==1.0.2
argparse==1.2.1
dj-database-url==0.3.0
django-classy-tags==0.6.1
django-cms==2.4.3
django-mptt==0.6.1
django-reversion==1.8.5
django-sekizai==0.8.1
djangocms-admin-style==0.2.5
djangocms-column==1.5
djangocms-file==0.1
djangocms-flash==0.1
djangocms-googlemap==0.2
djangocms-inherit==0.1
djangocms-installer==0.7.2
djangocms-link==1.5
djangocms-picture==0.1
djangocms-style==1.5
djangocms-teaser==0.1
djangocms-text-ckeditor==2.4.3
djangocms-video==0.1
html5lib==0.999
pytz==2014.10
requests==2.5.1
six==1.9.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Comment: Can you past models file content? Also check `VERSION_CHANGE` is present in `models.py` or not

Comment: I'm getting this error while creating the project.

Comment: can you please paste the output of ``pip freeze``?

Comment: Is 'reversion' in your INSTALLED_APPS? (check your settings)